# how to change font size of flutter material button?

Tags: button, flutter, text-size

How do I change Font size of a material button... is there a better way to do this?

```
new MaterialButton(
  height: 140.0,
  minWidth: double.infinity,
  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
  textColor: Colors.white,
  child: new Text("material button"),
  onPressed: () => {},
  splashColor: Colors.redAccent,
),
```

Comment: Unclear. Do you want to avoir the usage of `MaterialButton` ?

Comment: I'm experimenting with buttons and just looking for new ideas.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The widget architecture in Flutter makes this very simple: The child of the `MaterialButton` is a `Text` widget, which can be styled with its `style` property:

```
new MaterialButton(
  height: 140.0,
  minWidth: double.infinity,
  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
  textColor: Colors.white,
  child: new Text(
    "material button",
    style: new TextStyle(
      fontSize: 20.0,
      color: Colors.yellow,
    ),
  ),
  onPressed: () => {},
  splashColor: Colors.redAccent,
);
```

Comment: What did you add to my solution?

Answer (score 19):

You can make use of the [`style` attribute of your `Text` widget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Text/style.html).

```
MaterialButton(
  ...
  child: Text(
    'material button',
    style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 20.0, // insert your font size here
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 3):

### There are 2 ways to define Font size

**1) Inline set random font size like a newie to Flutter**

```
Text('item ${++index}', style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        fontSize: 32)
```

**2) Use Predefined Typography Font Sizes from Apps Material Theme**

This is a much better approach. This way you can define font sizes in one place and it will apply automatically in your entire Application.

```
Text('item ${++index}', style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.green,
                        fontSize: Theme
                            .of(context)
                            .textTheme
                            .headline1?.fontSize?? 32
                      )
```

Define Global Theme class :

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// Global Theme For App
class AppTheme {
  ThemeData buildThemeData() {
    return ThemeData(
        // Global Color Style
        primarySwatch: Colors.blueGrey,
        primaryColor: Colors.blueGrey[800],
        accentColor: Colors.tealAccent,

        // Global Text Style
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          headline1: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 72.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontFamily: 'Cutive',
          ),
          headline6: TextStyle(fontSize: 36.0),
          bodyText2: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
        ));
  }
}
```

Now Apply it in Entry point of App:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'theme.dart';
import './widgets/home.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(MainApp());
}
// This widget is the root of your application.
class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: AppTheme().buildThemeData(),
      home: MyStatelessWidget(), 
    );
  }
}
```

**The third Approach I use is I define components I gonna use anyways for header, label, etc and reuse them**

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Header extends StatelessWidget {
  Header({
    required this.title,
  });

  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      title,
      style: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 32,
          foreground: Paint()
            ..shader = ui.Gradient.linear(
              const Offset(0, 10),
              const Offset(40, 20),
              <Color>[
                Colors.red,
                Colors.blue,
              ],
            )),
    );
  }
}
```

This way setting header in all widget reduce to 1 line:

```
        Header(title: "Hello World"),
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `ThemeData`, you can globally set the text attributes for buttons:

```
const ColorScheme _scheme = ColorScheme.light();
const Color _primaryColor = TranscarentColors.primary;

final ThemeData theme = ThemeData(
  primaryColor: _primaryColor,
  textTheme: const TextTheme(
    button: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
  ),
  buttonTheme: const ButtonThemeData(
    height: 140.0,
    minWidth: double.infinity,
    colorScheme: _scheme,
    splashColor: Colors.redAccent,
    buttonColor: _primaryColor,
    textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
  ),
);
```

...which can be passed as a parameter to `MaterialApp()`

Answer (score 0):

```
Link(
                    uri: Uri.parse(
                        'https://google.com/'),
                    target: LinkTarget.blank,
                    builder: (ctx, openLink) {
                      return TextButton.icon(
                        onPressed: openLink,
                        label: const Text('Google'),
                        icon: const Text(''),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
```

> `**Blockquote**`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.